# php curl function not giving the required result

Tags: php, curl

I need help with API Integration. When I echo the variable `$url`, I get the result, but I do not know why cURL is not working for me:

```
<?php 

    $token="43e6c623dda8f35df4bXXXfa5f0ec57d58e91154a "; 
    $format="json";
    $waybill="974510010010";
    $ref_nos="";//either this or waybill
    $verbose="0";// meta info need to append in url



    $url="https://test.delhivery.com/api/packages/json/?token=".$token."&format=".$format."&waybill=".$waybill."&ref_nos=".$ref_nos."&verbose=".$verbose;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    $return = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $return;

 ?>
```

Comment: Is this code causing any error? Can you show output/error message?

Comment: Firstly can you use curl to pull back a minimal web page? i.e. test with a different url.

Comment: your error is `Login or API Key Required`

Comment: the error i am getting is: {"Error": "parameter ref_ids/ref_nos or waybill is required"}. but  i have passed value for waybill

Comment: perhaps an aside, but should your token have the trailing whitespace?

Comment: if i echo the variable $url i am getting the output. but with the cURL function its giving me the error

Comment: Got it. Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the service you are connecting to?

It could be that the service requires the data as POST variables as opposed to the GET parameters you are sending. 
Or perhaps some error handling on server that does not validate the waybill value you are sending. The ref_nos variable is also empty, which some applications could interpret as invalid. A tips would be to omit the ref_nos variable from the request string if its value is empty.